# Working with vectors and structs

Tags: c++

If I create a vector and fill it with 64 of these structs like so

```
struct movementType { int x, y , moves;};
vector<movementType> myVector(64);
```

How can I use the algorithms now that the type isn't an int, double, string etc. ?

Lets take the the fill_n algorithm. If you have

```
vector<int> someOtherVector(64);
```

We can fill it like this

```
fill_n (someOtherVector.begin(),64,20);
```

If I try this with my movementType vector, I get an error

```
MovementType empty;
empty.x = 5;
empty.y = 6;
empty.moves = 7;
fill_n (someOtherVector.begin(),64,empty);
```

So how can I use the STL algorithms using these types in my vector?

Thanks!

Comment: where is `fill_n()` defined and/or what does it do?

Comment: @SamIam `std::fill_n` is an algorithm in the C++ standard library.

Comment: If you get an error, don't just say so, tell WHAT error you get. That would help a lot.

Comment: Just [tested it and it works](http://ideone.com/EHbNu3). Does `someOtherVector` actually have any elements in it? Otherwise, you'll get a runtime error.

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't actually say what error you get, we have to make guesses about the solution. Also, given that [this test code works](http://ideone.com/EHbNu3), I assume you must be making a mistake elsewhere.

Are you getting a runtime error, such as a segmentation fault? If so, then the problem will be that the vector you're trying to fill, `someOtherVector` doesn't have enough elements in it. Have you actually defined it as `std::vector<movementType> someOtherVector(64)` or just `std::vector<movementType> someOtherVector`. `std::fill_n` assigns the given value to each of the elements of the container you're filling, so if there are no elements there you have a problem. So make sure your vector has enough elements in it.

The alternative here is to use `std::back_inserter` to add the elements to an empty vector:

```
std::vector<movementType> someOtherVector;
std::fill_n(std::back_inserter(someOtherVector), 64, empty);
```

But then, you really should just do:

```
std::vector<movementType> someOtherVector(64, empty);
```

Answer (score 1):

`fill_n (someOtherVector.begin(),64,empty);` doesn't make much sense, you are trying to fill a `vector<int>` with your `movementType`. If you want to fill a `vector<movementType>` the following would work (assuming you already declared `vector<movementType> myVector(64);`)
:

In C++11:

```
fill_n(myVector.begin(), 64, movementType{1, 2, 3});
```

Or C++03:

```
movementType m = {1, 2, 3};
fill_n(myVector.begin(), 64, m);
```

Comment: The asker mentions that it works for `vector<int>` but not for `vector<movementType>`.

Comment: @sftrabbit: Yes, `fill_n (someOtherVector.begin(),64,20);` would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can write operators for your class so that it behaves like a primitive type for the algorithms you want to use, or, in cases where the algorithm takes a function object to perform the operation, write a lambda or functor class and pass it to the algorithm.

In this case, the operator is `operator=`:

```
struct movementType
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int moves;

    movementType& operator=(int i)
    {
        // which member do you want to assign "i" to?
    }
};
```

Comment: No need to provide an assignment operator in this case. The compiler generated one is fine.

Comment: The compiler will generate a `movementType::opeartor=(const movementType&)` but not a `movementType::operator=(int)` (although I had first written `movementType::operator=(const movementType&)` and then edited it).

Comment: @user1610015: And why do you think he needs a conversion assignment operator?  Nothing in the question makes me think that's needed.

Comment: OP needs either a copy constructor or an assignment operator (or move versions of those in C++11). All of those would be provided by the compiler for the `struct` in question.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you need to provide a constructor to your structure, which in c++ behaves pretty much like a class. Somethink like

```
struct movementType 
{ 
  movementType(int X, int Y, int Moves) : x(X), y(Y), moves(Moves) { }  // Constructor with 3 int's
  movementType(const movementType &MT) : x(MT.x), y(MT.y), moves(MT.moves) { } // Copy constructor
  int x, y , moves; 
};
```

and then use

```
fill_n(someOtherVector.begin(),64, movementType(5,6,7));
```

Comment: I highly doubt this is related to the problem.

Comment: @MooingDuck Can you elaborate??

Comment: He appears to be correctly constructing and initializing `movementType` already.  He seems to be filling a `vector<int>` with `movementType` objects.

Comment: I hope that he defined the vector properly. The problem I can see is that the fill_n algorithm is using a bit-by-bit copy constructor guessed by the compiler. Not all compilers do this or guess right, although in this case it is an easy guess. So defining the object constructor, a copy constructor, or as another answer proposed a `=` operator should help avoiding this problem. Note that, as @ Zyx 2000 said, if we knew the error, it would be easier to help.

Comment: `fill_n` is required to use the defaulted copy operator, which (since this is a POD) _is_ a byte-copy, and that is perfectly fine.  There's no need for a constructor or assignment operator of any sort.   The fourth comment on the OP demonstrates this.